# x axis gets transformed to floats

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot my data grouped by year, and for each year, i want to count the number of users. Below, i just transformed the date column from float to integer.

This is my plot[image]

If you see the x-axis, my year ticker seems to have become a float and the each ticker is 0.5 tick apart.

How do i make this purely an integer?

---

Changing the groupby has the same result:
[image]

---

ticks are still 2 spaces apart after converting the year column to a string format

```
df['year'] = df['year'].astype(str)
```

:
[image]

Comment: You seem to be grouping by a Series. Try `df_train.groupby('year').count()['id'].plot()`

Comment: yes its the same result

Comment: Try `df['year'] = df['year'].astype(int)`
or `df['year'] = df['year'].astype(str)`

Comment: It was already in 'int' dtype. But when i changed to 'str' it worked. So weird. Thanks for your help!

Comment: well actually the tick still looks weird, you can see the update

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The expectation that using integer data will lead a matplotlib axis to only show integers is not justified. At the end, each axis is a numeric float axis.

The ticks and labels are determined by locators and formatters. And matplotlib does not know that you want to plot only integers.

Some possible solutions:

#### Tell the default locator to use integers

The default locator is a `AutoLocator`, which accepts an attribute `integer`. So you may set this attribute to `True`:

```
ax.locator_params(integer=True)
```

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.DataFrame({"year" : [2010,2011,2012,2013,2014],
                     "count" :[1000,2200,3890,5600,8000] })

ax = data.plot(x="year",y="count")
ax.locator_params(integer=True)

plt.show()
```

#### Using a fixed locator

You may just tick only the years present in the dataframe by using `ax.set_ticks()`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.DataFrame({"year" : [2010,2011,2012,2013,2014],
                     "count" :[1000,2200,3890,5600,8000] })

data.plot(x="year",y="count")
plt.gca().set_xticks(data["year"].unique())
plt.show()
```

#### Convert year to date

You may convert the year column to a date. For dates much nicer ticklabeling takes place automatically.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.DataFrame({"year" : [2010,2011,2012,2013,2014],
                     "count" :[1000,2200,3890,5600,8000] })

data["year"] = pd.to_datetime(data["year"].astype(str), format="%Y")
ax = data.plot(x="year",y="count")

plt.show()
```

In all cases you would get something like this:

[image]

Comment: for using pd.to_datetime, why didnt `df['year'] = df['date_account_created'].dt.year` work though.

Comment: Because `.dt.year` gives you an integer, and so the first paragraphs of this answer apply again.

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Use min and max to get the range of years to use in axis ticks
year_min = df['year'].min()
year_max = df['year'].max()

df['year'] = df['year'].astype(str) # Prevents conversion to float

plt.xticks(range(year_min, year_max, 1)) # Sets plot ticks to years within range
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

a solution that worked for me was to first convert the column to int and in a second step again to a string:

```
df['year'].astype(int)
df['year'].astype(str)
```

This might be more or less a "quick and dirty" workaround for the usage of a locator.